# Find top 5 buyers by transactions in each year in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a task, i have a table contains 3 columns:

buyer
yearx
trx

I want to find top 5 buyers by transactions in each year in MySQL. Is there fastest query? Because i do manually make some tables for each year (there are 10 tables) and get top buyer, and then i join them

Thank You

Comment: Show sample data and expected output. Which MySQL version?

Comment: If you want people to answer you if there is a faster/fastest query, you should show your current attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the provided information I assume this query might be helpful:

```
SELECT yearx, buyer, sum
FROM (
  SELECT yearx, buyer, SUM(trx) AS sum,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY yearx ORDER BY SUM(trx) DESC) AS rn
  FROM buyers
  GROUP BY yearx, buyer
) ranked
WHERE rn <= 5
ORDER BY yearx ASC, sum DESC;
```